# my shoes have come apart OR torn?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is come apart used for torn clothes and shoes?

In the title which is the correct expression should be used ?

What is the difference between clothes torn and come apart ?

Comment: I would tend toward My shoes "have fallen apart." This is because shoes, unlike the other basic clothing we wear, have a mixed component of parts, which are made out of different materials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Come apart**, as Maciej implies, means that the method that joins two distinct pieces has failed. With clothing, or with the "upper" section of a shoe, it would be a seam; with the sole of a shoe the method could be stitching or, in the case of sports shoes|trainers|sneakers, etc, glue.

A **tear** (verb 'to tear' intransitive) is a rip that can occur at any location, the result of the fabric catching or snagging on something sharp or pointed.

Comment: that was elaborate. So what should i say e.g. a glued tail of a kite came apart or came off ? - Thanks

Comment: Just trying to add some additional related vocabulary :-)

Comment: *Came off*, unless the tail itself was made of several sections, and the break occurred where two of these sections where joined.

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat more common to use "come apart" when referring to breaking into pieces the thing has been made of (glued, seamed, etc) - so if your shoe has come apart, that would mean that the seams broke, and not that it has been cut in an arbitrary place.